# get child div id of clicked class using jquery

Tags: jquery, xhtml

My code is

```
<div class="timeline_off"></div>
<div id="1851" class="year">1851</div>
```

I would like to get the id of the class 'year' once timeline_off is clicked using jquery.So the output should be 1851.Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.timeline_off').click( function () {
  var year = $(this).next('.year').attr('id');
});
```

So in laymans terms,
when timeline_off is clicked, the variable year is set to be equal to the id attribute of the next item having the class 'year'.

Comment: Brilliant...I was using children..:p

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".timeline_off").on("click",function(){
  var id = $(this).next(".year").prop("id");
  console.log(id);
  alert(id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/njM6t/1/)

New jQuery version will also provides '`prop()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".timeline_off").on("click",function(){
  var id = $(this).next(".year").attr("id");
});
```